# What is the difference between these two styles of writing functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am struggling to find out what is better between following two versions of Javascript fucntions

```
var FirstName = function(){
    var value = 0;

    this.getValue = function(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

and

```
var FirstName = function(){
    var value = 0;

    return {
        getValue: function(){
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

I do understand that the latter one forms a closure but I do not understand, from usage perspective what advantage does closure in second style provide over the first one?

EDIT: Based on comment from Felix, both the functions form closure. So semantically there is no difference between these two functions (as far as I understand them). So which is a preferred way? Is there any guideline?

Comment: In both cases the functions form closures.

Comment: The second one is 3 levels deep in indentation before even doing anything...

Comment: Thanks for correction Felix. But then is there any recommended way of writing JavaScript functions?

Comment: There's no recommended way, both are correct. When you got a lot of `this` going on the second option might be clearer.

Comment: @Esailija Not sure what difference done indentation make?

Comment: @Suhas You could read this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/if-you-need-more-than-3-levels-of-indentation-youre-screwed

Answer (score 0):

The second way seems a little redundant in this case. But I'm sure there are cases where it may be more beneficial to use the second way. I personally go with the first one just because it makes for cleaner and less confusing code usually. It's just a preference thing. Whichever you like and whichever is consistent with the rest of the code you are working on. Consistency is the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

The first method does not return anything but just creates the function as a global variable, whereas the second returns the inner function as a member of an object.

By *returning* the inner function, you can set and maintain different states of the function throughout your code, whereas with the first one, it will overwrite the method every time you run it. Seems like the latter is more flexible..

You can mess around with this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jksuK/) I made.

Comment: It is assumed that `new` is used here to construct the objects (because of the function name starting with UpperCase), though it's redundant in the second one because it returns plain objects in any case. There are many ways to create closures, returning a function is just one.

Comment: I see. I was going off the link in my post as a reference. Guess it wasn't accurate (though it had 626 vote-ups).. I will update.

Comment: Yeah, in fact the very first comment to that answer is criticizing that claim. It should definitely be edited...